# htaccess redirect secure URL, redirect old assets to Amazon S3, only for https

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following URL, I would like to redirect all css, images & javascript to my amazon s3 bucket.

```
# I have these URL's (and more)
https://secure.mydomain.co.uk/styles/donate/style.css
https://secure.mydomain.co.uk/js/donate/jquery.min.js
https://secure.mydomain.co.uk/images/donate/help-icon.png

# I would like to redirect all CSS, JS & Image files to:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.co.uk/static/$1

# So the URLs should be
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.co.uk/static/styles/donate/style.css
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.co.uk/static/js/donate/jquery.min.js
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.co.uk/static/images/donate/help-icon.png

# All other .php files, I want served using my normal secure.mydomain.co.uk
https://secure.mydomain.co.uk/other/php/files.php
```

I have tried the following, but it don't work as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^secure.mydomain.co.uk/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^secure.mydomain.co.uk/(.*) https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.co.uk/static/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

I have created a CNAME to point to our S3 bucket, but I cannot use a CNAME for the secure request (amazon don't allow this), So instead I would just like to forward all requests for assets (`css, images & js files`) to Amazon S3 to get the content via `https` via amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to fix your `RewriteCond` - currently it will redirect **all** requests, regardless of URI. You want to restrict it to only allow the filenames you want. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^secure.mydomain.co.uk/(.*).[php|js|css|gif|jpg]$ [NC]
```

This should redirect all files ending with php, js, css, gif, or jpg - and only those files.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I needed.
Basically, I have assets on my server, I have copied them over to `S3`, and would now like to redirect all my links to my `S3` bucket (So I can serve them via `https`).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.mydomain\.org.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule filename\.min\.js https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/path/to/js/filename.min.js [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule another\.min\.js https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/path/to/js/another.min.js [L,R=301,NC]
```

So basically, all requests for `filename.min.js` are redirected to my amazon bucket, and served from there.

There is probably a better way to do this (I'm not great with `.htaccess` rules), but adding each file I need served individually seems to work. (I only need these files redirected).

I would like all other requests to my `secure.` subdomain to be served normally via my app & asset-store (And not redirected to amazon).